# Property forChild does not exist on type typeof IonicModule Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, typescript

Criei um novo projeto ionic 2:

```
 ionic start myApp blank --V2
```

Até ai blza, só que quando vou criar uma nova pagina:

```
ionic g page login
```

Ele ta dando o seguinte erro abaixo:

```
Typescript Error
Property 'forChild' does not exist on type 'typeof IonicModule'.
E:/workspace/Ionic/myApp/src/pages/login/login.module.ts
imports: [
  IonicModule.forChild(Login),
],
```

E ele esta gerando os seguintes arquivos:

```
1.login.html
2.login.ts
3.login.module.ts
4.login.scss
```

Obs: antes também não gerava: `login.module.ts`
E também vi que no:
`ionic info` apareceu o `Ionic Framework Version: 3.0.1` que antes não aparecia, mais eu não rodei nenhuma atualização apenas criei novo app:

```
ionic info

Your system information:

 ordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic Framework Version: 3.0.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.2
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.
ios-deploy version: Not install
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 7
Node Version: v7.8.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solução:

Importar o `IonicPageModule` ao invez de `IonicModule`

Mudar de:

```
imports: [
  IonicModule.forChild(Login),
],
```

Para:

```
imports: [
  IonicPageModule.forChild(Login),
],
```