# Module.ts ionic 2

Tags: ionic2, typescript, angular-module

Eu atualizei o ionic 2 e o angular, mas agora quando gero uma página ele automaticamente cria um arquivo module.ts dentro da pasta da pagina junto com o html, scss e o arquivo ts, alguém sabe como fazer a aplicação funcionar? pois quando tento carregar com ionic serve aparece erro justamente não reconhecendo este module.ts da pagina criada, alguém tem alguma solução?

Comment: Poste o erro que está sendo gerado.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Property forChild does not exist on type typeof IonicModule Ionic 2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/198203/property-forchild-does-not-exist-on-type-typeof-ionicmodule-ionic-2)

Answer (score 0):

Esse novo arquivo module é para utilizar o lazy loading (que do meu ponto de vista melhorou MUITO a performance).

Caso não queira utilizar o lazy loading e continuar com o ionic como estava basta deletar esse arquivo module e no seu HTML deletar o seletor `@IonicPage` que ele também coloca, ai depois você faz sua rotina de adicionar a pagina no `app.modules.ts` e segue a vida.

Caso queira deixar o arquivo e fazer lazy loading, faça o seguinte:

Deixe seu arquivo `paginaNova.module.ts` assim:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NovaPagina} from './NovaPagina';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular'; // ele cria com IonicModule e isso da erro, tem que ser IonicPageModule

@NgModule({
    declarations: [NovaPagina],
    imports: [IonicPageModule.forChild(NovaPagina)],
    exports: [NovaPagina]
})
export class NovaPaginaModule { } //tem que ser assim: nomeDaPaginaModule
```

Não precisa importar essa pagina no seu `app.module.ts` e nem nas páginas quando for chamar essa página nova, basta apenas usar o nome dela dentro de aspas, então um push de página nova que era assim

```
import { NovaPagina } from '../novaPagina';

mInhaFuncao(){
  this.navCtrl.push(NovaPagina);
}
```

Passa a ser

```
mInhaFuncao(){ // Não precisa mais importar a página.
  this.navCtrl.push("NovaPagina");
}
```

Faça isso para todas as páginas do projeto e seja feliz, basta criar um module pra casa página e importar o `IonicPage` no `pagina.ts` e coloca-lo sob o @Component. Da um trabalhinho, mas vale a pena.

Espero ter ajudado :D